# Can I port a .NET project to .NET Core and use a DLL dependency from .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I was looking at the possibility of porting a small project from Windows .NET framework to Ubuntu (linux) using open source .NET Core. But my project has a dependency from another much bigger .NET 4.0 project. Can I just add a reference to the .NET 4 DLL dependency?

Comment: You won't be able to create a netcoreapp1.0 if you have a dependency that require full .NET Framework. You could target net451+ in your app but since you want to run it on Linux you would have to use Mono. Unfortunately there are problems with Mono (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9012) - making it work is hacky at best

Answer (score 2):

Any dependencies of a .NET Core project must also support .NET Core. So, if you have a dependency that requires .NET Framework 4, you won't be able to build your new project on .NET Core.

You'll have to replace the dependency with one that supports `netstandard1.X` in order to use it in a .NET Core project.